# typescript not complaining About not declaring types in constructor

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and I was expecting typescript to throw an error for not declaring types for my constructor but unfortunately I am not..

So I was curious why i am not getting an error.

this is what I am doing

```
export interface BaseConfig {
    app: express.Application, 
    routePermission: number,
    context: any
}

export class BaseConfig implements BaseConfig {
    constructor(
        context,
        authentication = false,
        authenticatedRoute = USER_TYPE.LOGGED_IN_NORMAL_USER
    ) {
        //intitalize Express App
        this.routePermission = authenticatedRoute

        this.context = context
        this.app = express()
```

This, is my `tsconfig`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`noImplicitAny` should be set to true. When false, it means implicit any is accepted, and variables declared without a type thus have, implicitly, the type `any`.

Answer (score 1):

`authentication` and `authenticatedRoute` parameters types are inferred from the default values, but `context` has `any` type by default, because you set `noImplicitAny` to `false` in the compilerOptions. See [Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for more information about compiler flags.